# Remove part of the string between the comments along with the comments

Tags: python, algorithm

Here's a string. I want to remove a C-style comments with the comments itself. **Without using regex**

```
a = "word234 /*12aaa12*/"
```

I want the output to be just:

> word234

Comment: Why don't you want to use a regex? What have you tried?

Comment: I want just to write an algorithm with manual selection. For example if the character in a string is / and * it will delete everything until the next */, i.e. the next comment. Can you help me please?

Comment: so what you tried so far ? what do you have issues doing : iterate over string, check char ?

Comment: As a general rule, you'd loop over the string with a `comment_depth` variable set to `0` initially. Every time you encounter a `/*` increment the depth. When you encounter a `*/` decrement. If it's `0` put the character into a new string. Return that resulting string.

Comment: I'm new to Python. Can you please write any code similar to your answer?

Comment: @Chris can the C-style comments be nested?

Comment: @mozway If they can't, the logic gets easier.

Comment: @Chris I did both :p the algo is almost the same

Comment: What behaviour do you want if there is an unmatched opening `'/*'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple algorithm that keep the state over 2 characters and uses a flag to keep or not the characters.

```
a = "word234 /*12aaa12*/ word123 /*xx*xx*/ end"

out = []
add = True
prev = None
for c in a:
    if c == '*' and prev == '/':
        if add:
            del out[-1]
        add = False
    if c == '/' and prev == '*':
        add = True
        prev = c
        continue
    prev = c
    if add:
        out.append(c)
s2 = ''.join(out)
print(s2)
```

Output:

```
word234  word123  end
```

If you want to handle nested comments (not sure if this exists, but this is fun to do), the algorithm is easy to modify to use a flag that counts the depth level:

```
a = "word234 /*12aaa12*/ word123 /*xx/*yy*/xx*/ end"

out = []
lvl = 0
prev = None
for c in a:
    if c == '*' and prev == '/':
        if lvl == 0:
            del out[-1]
        lvl -= 1
    if c == '/' and prev == '*':
        lvl += 1
        prev = c
        continue
    prev = c
    if lvl == 0:
        out.append(c)
s2 = ''.join(out)
print(s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) to search for occurrences of `/*` and `*/` in the string.

`str.find` returns the indices of `/*` and `*/`. `str.find` returns `-1` if it doesn't find `/*` in the string. We can use that as a stop condition in a loop, searching for the next comment until there are no more comments.

Then, we can use these indices with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join all the non-comment substrings into one string.

```py
def indices_c_comments(s):
    yield 0
    i = s.find('/*')
    while i != -1:
        j = s.find('*/', i)
        yield from (i, j+2)
        i = s.find('/*', j)
    yield len(s)

def strip_c_comments(s):
    g = indices_c_comments(s)
    return ''.join(s[i:j] for i,j in zip(g, g))

for s in ('text/*comment*/text/*comment*/text', 'text/*comment*//*comment*/text', 'text/*comment*/', '/*comment*/'):
    print('"{}"  -->  "{}"'.format(s, strip_c_comments(s)))
# "text/*comment*/text/*comment*/text"  -->  "texttexttext"
# "text/*comment*//*comment*/text"  -->  "texttext"
# "text/*comment*/"  -->  "text"
# "/*comment*/"  -->  ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing the proposed answer from @mozway:

*(Conditions left more explicit than necessary, for demonstration purposes.)*

```
def remove_comments(s, start_tok='/*', end_tok='*/', nested=True, raise_on_imbalance=True):
    lvl    = 0
    output = ""
    i      = 0
    while i < len(s):
        start_len_chs = s[i:i+len(start_tok)]
        end_len_chs   = s[i:i+len(end_tok)]
        if start_len_chs == start_tok and nested:
            lvl += 1
            i += len(start_tok)
        elif start_len_chs == start_tok and not nested and lvl == 0:
            lvl = 1
            i += len(start_tok)
        elif start_len_chs == start_tok and not nested and lvl != 0:
            output += start_len_chs
            i += len(start_tok)
        elif end_len_chs == end_tok and nested:
            lvl -= 1
            i += len(end_tok)
        elif end_len_chs == end_tok and not nested and lvl != 0:
            lvl = 0
            i += len(end_tok)
        elif end_len_chs == end_tok and not nested and lvl == 0:
            output += end_len_chs
            i += len(end_tok)
        elif lvl == 0:
            output += s[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            i += 1
    if raise_on_imbalance and (start_tok in output or end_tok in output):
        raise ValueError("Imbalanced comment tokens")
    return output
```

You really should make an attempt at doing this yourself. If you don't understand what's going on in the answers provided, you've gained nothing from this.